# D3 Connecting different data to 2 drop down menu

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drop-down-menu, scatter-plot

I have a scatterplot created from a .js files containing information about GNI and road traffic mortality. My problem is, how do I create two different drop down menus? y axis target right now is a drop down of the different road user categories. But the same drop down is being applied to continents. I know I should be using

```
        .selectAll("option")
        .data(countries).enter()
        .append("option")
        .text(function(d) { return d.continents; });
```

but I don't know how and where to connect it to the continents drop down target I've created without overwriting the y axis target (that is currently doing what it's supposed to do.)

I just want the y-axis and the continents target to be showing their appropriate selections.

**This is my code:**

```
function createButtons() {
// this array will be the list of dropdown menus
// each element will have a name and the target measure it will change

var buttonsData = [
    {name:"y axis", target: "y"},
    {name:"continents", target: "continents"}
];

var buttonGroups = d3.select("#buttons").selectAll(".buttonGroup")
    .data(buttonsData).enter()
    .append("span").attr("class", "buttonGroup");


// add a label to each <span> and set the text to be the name of the dropdown 
// this name is defined in the array above
buttonGroups.append("label").html(function(d){return d.name;});


// add a <select> dropdown tag to the <span> tag
buttonGroups.append("select")
    // when the dropdown selection changes, this event handler is called
    .on("change", function(d) {
        // find the index of the selection
        var selectedIndex = d3.select(this).property('selectedIndex');
        // here is where the target comes into play.

        if (d.target == "y") {
            yAxisIndex = selectedIndex;
        }

        else if (d.target == "continents") {
            continentIndex = selectedIndex;

            /*if ((sizeIndex >= 0) && (sizeIndex <=25)) {
                countries = countries.slice(0, 25);
                updateVis(false);
            }*/

        }

        // and update the vis, this will change the scales, labels, and reposition/resize the circles
        //creates the animation
        updateVis(true);
    })

    // add options to each <select> tag.
    // these options are coming from the countries array and are bound the same way as above
        .selectAll("option")
        .data(headers).enter()
        .append("option")
        //set the text of each option to the data elements from headers array
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add the data to your buttonsData

```
var buttonsData = [
    {name:"y axis", target: "y", optionData: ["france", "germany", "australia"]},
    {name:"continents", target: "continents", optionData: ["europe", "oceania"]}
];
```

(You can add the optionData in if those arrays are already floating about somewhere in your code like so: `optionData: countries` and `optionData: continents`)

Then you can access it for creating the option list like so:

```
 .selectAll("option")
        .data(function(d) { return d.optionData; })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f2c526ho/